# How to generate bibliography both the end of a slide and end of a presentation

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

A presentation is a sequence of `beamer` slides. I am preparing a presentation for an audience consists of two groups. One group of them want to visualize different references at the end of every slide. Others like to go through all of them together at the end of the presentation. To make all of them satisfied I need to write the author-name-journal-year references both at the foot of every slides as well as at the end of the presentation.

For putting reference at the end of a slide we may use `\footcite{}` using the package `biblatex`. But it does not generate a bibliography at the end of the presentation.

To write bibliography at the end of the presentation we may use simple code like

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

        \frametitle{References}
        \bibliographystyle{alpha}
        \bibliography{library}

\end{frame}
```

This method does not generate bibliography at the end of the slides.

Even, these two methods are not compatible to each other, as using one prevents another to run. Thus, how can I prepare my presentation to satisfy all of the audiences? Hope there are solutions not known to me. Note that, I like to use `.bib` files for generating bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you can use `\footfullcite{key}` to add the full entry as a foornote and using `\printbibliography` at the end you will also have the complete bibliography. A little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xyyzzz.bib}
@article{bertram,
  author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces},
  journaltitle = jams,
  date         = 1996,
  volume       = 9,
  number       = 2,
  pages        = {529-571},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  shorttitle   = {Gromov invariants},
  annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with a \texttt{volume} and a
                  \texttt{number} field},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{xyyzzz.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test\footfullcite{bertram}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\bibname}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As a side note, try to convince the group that wants the entries as footnote that this is not a good idea.